# How do I append margin or padding around an absolutely positioned element after it's loaded?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors, css-position

So basically I have a layout like this:

```
<div id="header">
   <div id="elementAbsolute">
   <div id="headerElement1">
   <div id="headerElement2">
</div>

<div id="content">
etc etc
```

My problem is that div id "elementAbsolute" can be randomly turned on or off on the page. I have no control over that. When it's on it needs to appear underneath the header but before the content. Since it's absolutely positioned, it just appears over the content.  It does not create any vertical whitespace above or below itself obviously.

In this particular template, that element must be called where it is in the markup.  It can't be moved.  Is there a way, possibly through javascript, to say that if "elementAbsolute" is turned on and exists on the page inside the "header" div then move it between the header and content div and create some whitespace?

Also keep in mind that this template is used for multiple sites, so the whitespace can only be added if "elementAbsolute" exists within "header".

I was thinking along the lines of using the jQuery after() function to put an empty divs before and after it to create that space, but then my problem becomes I only want this function to run if "elementAbsolute" is on the page, otherwise I'll have whitespace there no matter what.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why not make it block instead of absolute when it opens?

Comment: A demo or jsfiddle would be of help.

Comment: What do you mean by "turned on or off"? Is it a display property or does it get rendered based on a condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If elementAbsolute is of a fixed height then a simple fix would be to add the whitespace to the headerElement 1 or 2 instead

```
#elementAbsolute + #headerElement1 + #headerElement2
{
  margin-bottom: 50; /* Size of absolute element /*
}
```

Comment: Good use of adjacent sibling selectors.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `+` (adjacent sibling) selector in CSS to target sibling elements. When possible it is a good idea to use CSS in-case the browser has JavaScript turned-off and to help reduce the CPU overhead of JavaScript code.

```
#special-padding {
    height : 0;
}
#header > #elementAbsolute + #special-padding {
    height : 50px;
}
```

This requires a slight re-write of your HTML so that the `#elementAbsolute` and `#special-padding` elements are right next to each other:

```
<div id="header">
   <div id="headerElement1">
   <div id="headerElement2">
   <div id="elementAbsolute">
   <div id="special-padding">
</div>
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/TsPkc/1/

Or you can add some `margin` to an element:

```
#header > #elementAbsolute ~ #headerElement2 {
    margin-bottom : 50px;
}
```

This will add some margin to the last element (`#headerelement2`) that is a child of the `#header` element.

Comment: The ~ selector is cool but it's CSS3 only. So no luck in IE 8 or earlier.

Comment: Good call, however `+` is supported back to IE7, so if the two elements are right next to each other in the DOM then that will work. I'll update my answer. Here is the support for the adjacent sibling selector (`~`): http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel2

Comment: Still, this solution requires modifying the original HTML. If you look at my solution no changes to the original page are required.

Answer (score 0):

`if(jQuery("div#elementAbsolute")) { // execute your code }`

Also, you want to be sure to have closing tags on your divs.

Comment: You don't need to select by div and then by id. jQuery("#elementAbsolute") is faster.